# use match and do not match in sed script

Tags: sed, match

I need to extract certain json data (that have datalist member) from the log file, but only of map value is not 200.

right now I have two sed scripts, one extracts json data from a log file:

```
sed -n 's/.*\({\"datalist\".*}\).*/\1/p' full.log > new.log
```

the other one skips data if map field has value 200:

```
sed -n '/.*\"map\":\"200\".*/!p' new.log > map.log
```

how to combine these two into one?

UPD: I have accepted answer for now, but I wonder why

```
sed -n 's/.*\({\"datalist\".*\"map\":\"\(?!200\)\".*}\).*/\1/p' full.log > new.log
```

doesn't work

Comment: The basic command for multiple sed conditions is `-e`. Anyway, I don't think it is useful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/"map":"200"/!s/.*\({"datalist".*}\).*/\1/p' full.log > new.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Strip out the "map:200" lines with grep before sending to sed:

```
grep -v "\"map\":\"200\"" full.log | sed -n 's/.*\({\"datalist\".*}\).*/\1/p' > new.log
```